# Pass a value by parameter and update it in the controller on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

**Description:**
I have a collection of items. I show them into the view using ng-repeat, and then when I select any of the items, I want to set the 'currentState' value into true or false depending on some actions. Finally show it into the view.

**Problem:**
When I pass 'currentState' to the controller, using ngClick, it's not being updated.

**Code:**

**VIEW**

```
 <md-select>
    <md-option ng-value="item.name" ng-click="exampleFunc(currentState)" ng-repeat="item in items>{{item.name}}</md-option>
 </md-select>
 <span>{{item.name}} - {{currentState}}</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller(...{
     $scope.items = [{name: ...}, {name: ...}];  //array of objects
     $scope.currentState = null;       //boolean var, null as default

     $scope.exampleFunc = function(aState) {           
        //some actions if true
         aState = true;
        //if false
         aState = false;
     }
});
```

The idea is use the same function ('exampleFunc') to update different independent values, for ex:

```
<md-select>
    <md-option ng-value="item.name" ng-click="exampleFunc(anotherState)" ng-repeat="item in items>{{item.name}}</md-option>
 </md-select>
 <span>{{item.name}} - {{anotherState}}</span>
```

Is there any possibility to do something like this.
Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ng-click="exampleFunc($parent.currentState)"
```

see this example https://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/ov3gftgs/1/

Comment: Hi jad-panda and thanks vey much for your answer. I want to do something like that, but also change the value into the function. For ex: in the fiddle, you set $scope.val = test and pass it to the function. Well, i want to modify that value into the function and return to view.

Comment: inside the function you can assign value to $scope.val = another_value https://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/ov3gftgs/2/

Comment: Yes, this is what i think at the beginning. However, I want to call the function in different places with different values. Somethig like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ov3gftgs/5/

Comment: So in the fiddle, if I call the function, depending on the value I pass, it will set to false into the function, and the show that result in the view

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/ov3gftgs/9/ are you trying to manipulate array of string or array of objects ?

Comment: array of objects, but it's not neccessry to use the array. The general idea is: pass different null values (val1, val2, ...) to a function using ngClick, then modify those values into the function and finally return them (modified) to view.

Comment: for that you can simply change the value on the $scope directly , why do you want to change the value of function parameter ?

Comment: Well let me explain. In the app I'm doing, the function is an angular material dialog ($mdDialog), so when I select an item a new window appear and I have to select one of two options (true or false). Depending on the option I selected a value on the $scope should be updated. I know I can update the $scope value directly, but I have to use the function twice with two different values, however I don't think it's a good idea to write the function twice...

Comment: The $scope values ($scope.val1 / $scope.val2) I mentioned are independent of the array